# How can I disable the validation of the step attribute of a specific input element of type 'number'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, validation

I'm using angular 1.5.5, and I'd like to exploit HTML5 form validation.
I'm no expert BW.

So I have something like this:

```
<input type="number" name="element1" ng-model="element1" step="{{range.step}}" min="{{range.min}}" max="{{range.max}} ..."/>
<input type="number" name="element2" ng-model="element2" .../>
<button type="submit" ...</button>
```

According to the spec the step value serves two purposes: 
1. It indicates the step number subtracted from, or added to, the value of the input element, and
2. it determines the valid values of the input element.
This is, of course, unfortunate. In my case, the range is very small, say between 0 and 1, and I'd like to set the step value to 0.1. However, I'd also like all values between 0 and 1 inclusively to be classified as valid.

Assume that element1 contains a value that invalidates the step condition.

First, it seems that the step-validation procedure does not work all the way---invalid values according to the above do not trigger the angular validity classes (e.g., scope.form.$invalid is false) and so I can proceed with the submission. This behavior, while probably results from a bug, is to my advantage, but I'm afraid that one day this bug will be fixed and then I'll be left with a problem.

Secondly, assume also that element2 contains a value that invalidates its condition, say the user entered a non-digital character. In this case, the validity classes are appropriately set (e.g., scope.form.$invalid is true) and I can abort the submission. However, a bubble appears next to element1 with the error message: "Please select a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 0.5 and 0.6.". Notice that element1 appears before element2 in the form. I would like to get a bubble with the appropriate error message next to element 2 instead.

Is it possible to somehow somewhere suppress the validation of the step condition of element1? If so, how? If not, do I have other options? Notice that I would like to retain HTML5 validation and have those bubbles displayed for (truly) invalid elements.

Comment: It'd be easier to make your own directive.

Comment: I can add a directive to fix the angular bug (.directive("step", function() {...), but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish what you're after if you use both `step` and `ng-step`.

Use `step` to specify the amount you want the value to increment/decrement with the HTML input up/down toggles.  Use `ng-step` to specify the validation you want Angular to perform on the value.  Without specifying `ng-step`, Angular will use the value of `step` for validation.

For example, you may want to increment values by 0.1 with the input toggles and separately validate the value is an increment of 0.01.  You could use the following input definition to accomplish this:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="model.field" step="0.1" min="0" max="1" ng-step="0.01"/>
```